# Refresh a content page without refreshing master page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have an admin layout

[image]

---

I have a master layout contain my :

- top nav
- left side nav

Each page is a view, I extend the master layout view, and update only the content section.

My goal is to refresh **only** a content page without refreshing master page.

---

Is there any **laravel package** for something like this ?

Comment: simple use ajax) or should I explain more?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short answer: **use AJAX**. There no real need to learn a JavaScript framework if it's that simple (unless you really want to). The below example uses jQuery and assumes you're clicking on the **Users** link in the navigation (all links there should have a `nav-item` class so they can be easily identified via that selector) and the link has the attribute `href="/admin/users"`. When clicked it loads the contents in the element with the class `content`:

```
$('.item-nav').click(function (event) {
    // Avoid the link click from loading a new page
    event.preventDefault();

    // Load the content from the link's href attribute
    $('.content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

If the route `admin/users` would return the users table with it's contents:

```
get('admin/users', function () {
    return view('users')->with('users', Users::all());
});
```

The above Laravel route example is of course simplified to showcase the idea that each item in your navigation should link to the contents that need to be displayed dynamically.

Comment: You always provide answer. I really appreciated your helps.

Answer (score 6):

You can use renderSections().

In your main controller action ( say AdminUsersController@getIndex ) you can render a particular section of your view depending on the request. This way if you do an ajax request to the same page you are on you can return only the section you require.

```
 if($request->ajax()) {
         return view('admin.users',$users)->renderSections()['content'];
 }

 return view('admin.users',$users);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with laravel livewire. By using **wire:poll** on your element inside your component.

Reference the docs here: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-poll